# sge can only run one task in one node

Tags: bash, shell, cluster-computing, centos7, sungridengine

I had built the SGE in a four-node cluster for source code. The operating system in Centos7. And when I submit some simple task in the cluster, I found that only one task was running in one node. What's the problem? Here is my task code:

```
sleep 60
echo "done"
```

and this is my cmd to submit the tasks:

```
DIR=`pwd`
option=""
for((i=0;i<5;i++));do
  qsub -q multislots $option -V -cwd -o stdout -e stderr -S /bin/bash $DIR/test.sh
  sleep 1
done
```

when run qstat -f, it shows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJgYx.png)

Comment: On your screenshot I see 3 jobs running on 3 nodes (job 505 on node332, job 506 on node335 and job 504 node336, if I am not mistaken.) What make you say there is a single task running on a single node?

Comment: I mean that node335 has 16 slots and job506 use only one, and there are two jobs waiting in the queue, why didn't the left two jobs running?

Comment: And when I view the file default/spool/qmaster/messages, I see the error:  "job 519.1 failed on host node332 assumedly before job because: can not find an unused add_grp_id"

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message about jobs failing because: "can not find an unused add_grp_id".  You should check what gid_range is set to in the sge configuration(both global and also if there is one per-host). It should be a range of otherwise unused group ids.  At least as many gids as you want jobs on a node.

If that isn't it try running qalter -w v and qalter -w p on one of the queued jobs to see why they aren't being started.